# ScreenCall process does not connect the call

Tags: twilio

I have a use case where someone calls my Twilio number and then Twilio tries to connect the caller with an agent. When the agent # picks up I use the ScreenCall process to make sure it is a human and they have to press a digit. The issue is as soon as I go into the ScreenCall process everything works on the agents side but when they press a number the caller is never connected to them.

What am I missing? As soon as I remove the screen call the caller and agent are connected as soon as the agent answers.

```
public ActionResult CallAgents(string From, string To, string CallSid)
    {
        var response = "<Response><Dial action = '" + Url.Action("EndCall", "Call") + "'>
 <Number action = '" + Url.Action("ScreenCall", "Call") + "'>1231231234</Number></Dial></Response>";

        return new TwiMLResult(response);
    }

 public ActionResult ScreenCall(string From, string To, string CallSid)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        response.BeginGather(new { action = "AnswerCall", numDigits = 1 })
            .Say("Press any key to accept the call.")
            .EndGather();


        return new TwiMLResult(response);
    }

 public ActionResult AnswerCall(string From, string To, string CallSid)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse().Say("Thank you, you are now being connected.").Record();

        return new TwiMLResult(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> response.BeginGather(new { action = "AnswerCall", numDigits = 1 })

`AnswerCall` in the above appears to simply be a string. The [`action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) of `<Gather>` expects an absolute or relative URL as a value. When the agent has finished entering digits Twilio will make a GET or POST request to this URL. After making this request, Twilio will continue the current call using the TwiML received in your response.

You can also check out a code complete call screening example in this tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/csharp/mvc#4

The snippet there when an agent screens the call looks like this:

```
// POST: Agent/ScreenCall
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ScreenCall(string from)
{
    var response = new TwilioResponse();
    var incomingCallMessage = "You have an incoming call from: " +
                              SpelledPhoneNumber(from);
    response.BeginGather(new {numDigits = 1, action = Url.Action("ConnectMessage")})
        .Say(incomingCallMessage)
        .Say("Press any key to accept")
        .EndGather();

    response.Say("Sorry. Did not get your response");
    response.Hangup();

    return TwiML(response);
}

// GET: Agent/ConnectMessage
public ActionResult ConnectMessage()
{
    return TwiML(new TwilioResponse()
        .Say("Connecting you now..."));
}
```

Comment: Found the issue. It breaks down give it a "record" command once the screenCall has processed and someone accepts the call. Figure it out by backing into what the sample was doing that I was not.